# Align reclyerview childers from bottom

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, layout

[image]

I'm trying to make chart with `reclyerview`. The issue that i'm having is i can't seem to make child items align from bottom, instead of the top of the reclyerview.

I have tried, `reverseLayout` and `stackFromEnd`

I have searched left and right. Still have no idea why does this happen.

Can anyone please help me. 
Any helpfull ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Setting the view holder to be a relative layout and you align the content to the bottom doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: @Medeiros I have tried to make child's parent align to bottom, that didn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda figured it out.

As i have static height, i created another wrapper around child, that was alligned to bottom, and the parrent set as specific height.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        >

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">


        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_time"
                style="@style/BoldWhiteText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="7.5"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Layout managers align items to top-start by default because it's the most stable in case `RecyclerView` has height of `wrap_content` which could cause some layout issues.

If your `RecyclerView` has fixed size you can try to extend layout manager you're using to force it to lay out items on bottom:

```
// inside your activity or fragment where you're initializing RecyclerView
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false) {
      @Override
      public void layoutDecoratedWithMargins(@NonNull View child, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
          // calculate available space in recyclerView
          int offset = getHeight() - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();
          // subtract height of item being laid out
          offset -= bottom - top;
          // lay out item lower than usual
          super.layoutDecoratedWithMargins(child, left, top + offset, right, bottom + offset);
      }
});
```